# How to verify that a matrix is a rotation matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matrices, matlab, rotations

Using Matlab, I want to know if

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
\cos(x) & \sin(x)\\ -\sin(x) & \cos(x)
\end{pmatrix}$$

is a rotation matrix. Hence,

$$\begin{pmatrix} \cos(x) & \sin(x)\\ -\sin(x) & \cos(x)
   \end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} \cos(x) & -\sin(x)\\ \sin(x) & \cos(x)
   \end{pmatrix}=I$$

$$\det(A)=1$$

Yet I'm not sure how to compute it, this is what I tried:

```
>> A=[cos(x) -sin(x);
sin(x) cos(x)]

A =

[ cos(x), -sin(x)]
[ sin(x),  cos(x)]

>> A'*A

ans =

[ cos(conj(x))*cos(x) + sin(conj(x))*sin(x), sin(conj(x))*cos(x) - cos(conj(x))*sin(x)]
[ cos(conj(x))*sin(x) - sin(conj(x))*cos(x), cos(conj(x))*cos(x) + sin(conj(x))*sin(x)]
```

Indeed, shouldn't the top left hand corner be $1$?

Here is something weird about the transposed:

```
>>A'
ans =

[  cos(conj(x)), sin(conj(x))]
[ -sin(conj(x)), cos(conj(x))]
```

Comment: try to verify what matlab ouputs for $A'$ and check if $x$ is already symbolized

Comment: @user340297 I did `syms x` before and added the output of $A'$

Comment: What do you get with $A.'$?

Comment: @Moo It gives right thing (i.e. no weird conj things) but then result to - A*A.' involves the term $\sin(x)^2 + \cos(x)^2$ which matlab does not simplify to $1$.

Comment: Try simplify...

Comment: `A'` is **not** the transpose of `A`; it is the **conjugate** transpose of `A`.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I didn't know... So what is the actual transpose?

Comment: @Marine1 The transpose is `A.'`. However, the two transposes are equivalent when the matrix is real.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is **real**, then it should be declared as such:

```
>> x = sym('x','real');
>> A = [cos(x) -sin(x); sin(x) cos(x)]

A =

[  cos(x), -sin(x)]
[  sin(x),  cos(x)]


>> A'

ans =

[  cos(x),  sin(x)]
[ -sin(x),  cos(x)]


>> A'*A

ans =

[ cos(x)^2+sin(x)^2,                 0]
[                 0, cos(x)^2+sin(x)^2]


>> simplify(ans)

ans =

[ 1, 0]
[ 0, 1]
```